# Query file size without opening it

Tags: haskell

Haskell has the `hFileSize` method - but this only works if you have permission to open the file. Is there a portable way to query a file's size without needing to actually open it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getFileStatus` and `fileSize` from the System.Posix module to do this:

```
import System.Posix
main = getFileStatus "/path/to/file" >>= print . fileSize
```

**Edit:** `System.Posix` is provided by the `unix` package, which only works on Linux and similar. However, the `unix-compat` package provides a `System.PosixCompat.Files` module which exports these same functions, and works on Windows. (And Linux?)

Comment: Edit: I assumed it would, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Looking at my package index, I see a `System.Posix.Types`, but GHCi gives me an error if I try to import any other POSIX modules.

Comment: Yeah, I know Windows does have some degree of POSIX support, so I thought it _might_ work...

Comment: Apparently the whole `unix` package does not work on windows. I can't try this, but you might have to install the `unix-compat` package on windows first

Comment: The package exposes `System.PosixCompat.Files`, which has a `getFileStatus` and a `fileSize`; the documentation suggests this should work on every platform.